# Hibernate Validator - Setting a default value after entity fails validation

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-validator

I want to validate the data in my EclipseLink entities before inserting them into the database using Hibernate Validator.

If the validation fails then I want to set default values on those entities.  Then I want to insert the data into the database and flag those entities as having failed validation with the relevant error messages.

Is the best way to do this to use the validator's isValid() method?

I am new to Hibernate Validator, googled and search stackoverflow but couldn't find a question similar to mine.

Comment: Hi Andrew, you got some progress on this ? Or found some way to achieve it from a functional standpoint ?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate by default validates the entity passed to save(), persist() or update()... before really do the stuffs after.

In your case, you can use the validator to validate your objects yourself. Then depends of the list of ConstraintViolation, you can identify invalid properties to fill the default values.

Example of using Hibernate validator API can be found [here](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/). ValidatorFactory  is your friend.